# argument type mismatch by Using BeanUtils.copyProperties

Tags: java

dto object:

```
public class DTOUser implements UserDetails {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -769714837633005963L;
private Long id;
private String account;
private String password;
private String statusStr;
private UserStatus status;
private int systemAdmin;
private long operator;
private String operateTime;
private String name;
private String company;
private String email;
private String telephone;
private List<DTOAuthority> dtoAuthorities = new ArrayList<DTOAuthority>();
private List<DTOAgreement> dtoAgreements = new ArrayList<DTOAgreement>();}
```

entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="adt_user")
public class User {
private long id;
private String account;
private String password;
private String statusStr;
private UserStatus status;
private int systemAdmin;
private long operator;
private String operateTime;
private String name;
private String company;
private String email;
private String telephone;
private Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<Authority>();
private Set<Agreement> agreements = new HashSet<Agreement>();}
```

i use bellow method to copy value to entity, but there is an exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot invoke com.hna.adt.orm.User.setAuthorities - argument type mismatch
```

what's wrong with it ?

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(entity, value);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
private List<DTOAuthority> dtoAuthorities = new ArrayList<DTOAuthority>();
```

vs.

```
private Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<Authority>();
```

If `BeanUtils.copyProperties` considers only the setters and getter of the elements and is not intelligent enough to figure out that `Set` and `List` are both collections and iterates and copies the elements one by one - which still requires that `Authority` is compatible with `DTOAuthority` - then it will throw this reflection error, then `Set` is not assignable from `List` i.e. not compatible.

If you try to do the same at compile time

```
entity.setAuthorities(value.getDtoAuthorities());
```

Then you get the same sessage as a compile error.

You should either change `dtoAuthorities`  to be a `Set` or `authorities` to be a `List`.

Comment: You could also use something like [Moo](http://github.com/geoffreywiseman/Moo) or Dozer that can do a more complicated kind of mapping with transformation.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the type of authorities and agreements, they do not match with other class definition. In order to beanutils to work properly, make sure the type of attributes matches.

Comment: As an extra note, BeanUtils only does a shallow copy.  From the javadoc: `Note that this method is intended to perform a "shallow copy" of the properties and so complex properties (for example, nested ones) will not be copied.`