# Is there a way to map a Set to a List with BeanUtils.copyProperties?

Tags: java, spring, mapping

I'm using `BeanUtils.copyProperties` to convert two beans.

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(organization, dtoOrganization);
```

I would like to have a `List` in one bean and a `Set` in the other one.

First bean:

```
public class Form {

  private Set<Organization> organization;

}
```

Second bean:

```
public final class DTOForm {

  private List<DTOOrganization> organization;

}
```

The result is an exception as stated here:
[argument type mismatch by Using BeanUtils.copyProperties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19064331/argument-type-mismatch-by-using-beanutils-copyproperties)

Is it possible to customize `BeanUtils.copyProperties` to achive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it using custom converters. Main idea is to register new converter for `Set`s using [`ConvertUtils.register(Converter converter, Class<?> clazz)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/ConvertUtils.html#register(org.apache.commons.beanutils.Converter,%20java.lang.Class)). It's not a problem to implement your custom set-to-list converter's [`convert(Class<T> type, Object value)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/Converter.html#convert(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object)) method.

Here is simple example for your issue:

**ListEntity, which has `List` property (don't ignore setters and getters, as far as I know, their existence is mandatory):**

```
public class ListEntity {
    private List<Integer> col = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Integer> getCol() {
        return col;
    }

    public void setCol(List<Integer> col) {
        this.col = col;
    }
}
```

**SetEntity, which has `Set` property:**

```
public class SetEntity {
    private Set<Integer> col = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<Integer> getCol() {
        return col;
    }

    public void setCol(Set<Integer> col) {
        this.col = col;
    }
}
```

**Simple test class to make in work:**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        SetEntity se = new SetEntity();
        se.getCol().add(1);
        se.getCol().add(2);
        ListEntity le = new ListEntity();
        ConvertUtils.register(new Converter() {
            @Override
            public <T> T convert(Class<T> tClass, Object o) {
                List list = new ArrayList<>();
                Iterator it = ((Set)o).iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    list.add(it.next());
                }
                return (T)list;
            }
        }, List.class);
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(le, se);
        System.out.println(se.getCol().toString());
        System.out.println(le.getCol().toString());
    }
}
```

The main idea of this code snipper: we register converter for all destination class `List` properties, it will try to convert some object `o` to `List`. Assuming, that `o` is a collection, we iterate over it and then return newly created list.

As a result, `le` will contains both `1` and `2` values. If you don't need this converter anymore, you can unregister it using [`ConvertUtils.deregister()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/ConvertUtils.html#deregister()).

Answer (score 1):

Converting from a set of one type to a list of another type is quite a stretch.

While you may be able to achieve it by creating custom JavaBeans PropertyEditors, I'd prefer to use a Mapper Framework like [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Yes, but I was trying to avoid adding another additional dependency to my project.